# Google Maps API Android NullPointerException

Tags: android, google-maps

buenas tardes.
El problema es que al ejecutar la aplicación en la que tengo un MapFragment, si no escribo código me va perfectamente pero si escribo el código para tener una referencia hacia un GoogleMap, me da error "NullPointerException", no se que podrá ser, alguna idea?

Aquí dejo el código resumido, con las partes importantes, el fallo me da cuando esta en la línea de getMapAsync(this);

```
public class EventCardViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{

private GoogleMap googleMap;

MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map){
    googleMap = map;
}
```

Aquí esta el fallo exacto:

```
08-09 14:51:22.754 8627-8627/eventoslpa.com.eventoslpa_final E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: eventoslpa.com.eventoslpa_final, PID: 8627
                                                                           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{eventoslpa.com.eventoslpa_final/eventoslpa.com.eventoslpa_final.activity.EventCardViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2750)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment.getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at eventoslpa.com.eventoslpa_final.activity.EventCardViewActivity.onCreate(EventCardViewActivity.java:85)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
                                                                               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo hacer comentarios todavia ;( tienes que tener en cuenta que

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapFragment);
```

se debe referenciar despues de `setContentView` en `onCreate`, o si es desde un fragment despues de haber inflado la vista.

Revisa en el layout que el nombre del `MapFragment` sea el mismo `mapFragment` y tambien verfica que este definido el `MapFragment` no `SupportMapFragment`